# How to show all games that I published in WP7 from a certain game?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to add a link in someway in each game that I publish such that it leads to a list of all published games by me.

That is possible and I can notice that in some games under the title "More Games".

I need to do that via C# using some library if anybody can tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that searching the marketplace for a publisher name returns all applications of that publisher and displays them in a list in the marketplace.

```
MarketplaceSearchTask marketplaceSearchTask = new MarketplaceSearchTask();

marketplaceSearchTask.SearchTerms = "Publisher's name";

marketplaceSearchTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are apps that access the market place so it is possible to access it from an application.

But if you just need to list the other games you have made with links and maybe an image then why not just download a static file from a web server somewhere? Just a simple web page that you update yourself would be perfectly fine, and if you wanted to do something more fancy you could download a JSON or XML file that you use as a game list.

This file would be easy to update without updating the game itself so there would be no need to update the game when you publish other games.

I think such an option will be much easier than accessing the marketplace from code.